# What is the most efficient way to run many subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python master script that runs 24 subprocesses, each of which will take a few hours to run and generate 100s of MBs of output. I have access to a machine with 8 CPUs.

My question is this: is it more efficient to control the number of subprocesses running at one time ie only start 8 subprocesses at a time and as one finishes, start another? Or should I just start all 24 and let the OS take care of them. Is the former more efficient than the latter?

Comment: micro-managing threads/processes is hard. I would leave it the OS scheduler if I were you (as long as you don't hit any critical performance drop).

Comment: Could you explain a little more about why it is hard georges|? I was just going to set up a queue of commands, start 8 and then have a loop that counts how many are active, adding another each time the count drops below 8. What am I missing here?

Comment: What if the counting process is "starved" by the other process ? What if you didn't implement a mutex and, when two process are finished at the same timee, your counter is only decrementing by one (overwriting) ? Race conditions are tricky and subtle : I suggest you to start every process and let the OS wake/sleep them.

Comment: need to know whether your processes are CPU bound, IO bound, or neither.

Comment: georges, taking your advice and letting the OS do it. Do you know of any resources online, that discuss the issues you raised? I couldnt find anything.

Comment: James, not completely sure what you mean by "bound"?